# Single letter answer options for quiz

Tags: translation

I have a trivia game that I'm translating into korean.

I usually use single letter answer options like:

```
A. John
B. Ashley
C. Peter
```

Would I have to present it differently for the Korean audience?

Comment: please post your attempt to make it easier for others to help you. "translate this for me" type of questions are usually disliked and your question may attract downvotes and get closed

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, you wouldn't really have to change your format for the Korean audience. But in case you have a very young (like preschoolers) or old audience (like >70), you can't be sure that your audience knows the alphabet. In that case, you would want to pick another numbering.

The most widely used "numbering system" for exam/quiz style single choice questions is Arabic numbers. 1., 2., 3., or ①, ②, ③. Not as common, but you can also go with Hangul consonants (ㄱ., ㄴ., ㄷ., ..., ㅎ., or ㉠, ㉡, ㉢, ..., ㉭) or Hangul syllables(가., 나., 다., ..., 하.) I don't think I've seen a lot of ㉮, ㉯, ..., but your audience will have no problem even if you go with this, too. Another problem with Hangul consonant/syllable numbering is that you can't have more than 14 choices, from ㄱ to ㅎ or from 가 to 하.

To see some real examples, you can image-search google with the keyword ["객관식 문제"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%EA%B0%9D%EA%B4%80%EC%8B%9D+%EB%AC%B8%EC%A0%9C&tbm=isch) or ["객관식 퀴즈"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%EA%B0%9D%EA%B4%80%EC%8B%9D+%ED%80%B4%EC%A6%88&tbm=isch).